# mongoose array not work when i use update function

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

**Data**:

```
{
    name : "a",
    regists:[
       {
           name : "1",
           isCancel: false
       },
       {
           name : "2",
           isCancel: false
       }
  ]
}
```

**Operation:**

```
model.update({
    'name':'a',
    'regists.isCancel' : false
},{
    $set :{
        'regists.$.isCancel' :true
    }
})
```

It's working when I run it the first time, but nothing changes when I run it afterwards.

Comment: set multi to true if you want to update multiple documents based on the condition. Here is the syntax for update

    db.collection.update(
       <query>,
       <update>,
       {
         upsert: <boolean>,
         multi: <boolean>,
         writeConcern: <document>
       }
    );

Hope it helps

Comment: model.update({
    'name':'a',
    'regists':{
                $elemMatch :{
                    isCancel : false,
                }
            }
},{
    $set :{
        'regists.$.isCancel' :true
    }
})